# User to User request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I am building an event application where user creates an event and invites his/her friends. I custom built the friend selector as selecting friends is one of the steps in the whole process(Facebook friend selector sends invitation right after click the invite button). After selecting friends I present that information along with other information to get user's confirmation. I have to notify invitees about this new event. Here are my options

Notifications (limited to app users)

Messages (limited to app users)

Requests (app to user are limited to app users but user to user are not)

So the only option I have is to use user to user request which currently is only possible with dialogAPI. I cannot use dialogAPI as I have a custom friend selector.

Is it possible to send user to user notifications/messages/requests to users who did not authorize the app yet? Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm sure you can imagine what a loop hole that would be.  Applications can not send anything other than requests to users who have not yet authenticated the application. More over, applications can not under any circumstances send messages.

Comment: As much as I understand the problem letting all apps sending user to user requests, it is hard to digest that authentic apps are loosing flexibility in building creative apps. :(

Any other ideas to let users know that they are invited?

Comment: You could always post on their wall (*cringe*)

Comment: That would be my last resort as I don't want to post to their wall without their RSVP but I guess I have no option

Comment: You can send message to your friend (that didn't authorized the app) from your application using [Send Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/). But the user who sends this must click on the Send button. You can send it to one user or multiple at once. Just fill the `to` property in `FB.ui`.